# Как получить всех сум value из объекта

Tags: javascript

```
const arr = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}]
const totalValue = 6 // ?
```

как получить totalValue с помощью reduce

мой вариант

```
arr.reduce((obj, total) => Object.values(obj) + total, 0)
```

Comment: что по твоему возвращает `Object.values(obj)`?

Comment: массив всех валюс

Comment: тогда почему ты массив складываешь с числом?

Comment: ну тут просто разные ключи по этому не знаю как делать

Comment: абстрагируйся от разных ключей. сейчас ты делаешь следующее `[1,2,3] + 0`, а нужно тебе сначала найти  сумму всех в массиве `[1,2,3]`

Comment: внутри reduce ?

Comment: да, один из вариантов

Comment: а какой самый лучший вариант получить totalValues ?

Comment: в чем ты оцениваешь лучшесть?

Comment: ну через reduce или через мап

Comment: и чем плох этот вариант 
const totalValue = arr.reduce((s, o) => s + Object.values(o)[0], 0)

Comment: map нельзя использовать если тебе не нужен массив результатов. А тебе он не нужен.

Comment: а ты можешь написать свой вариант решение ?

Comment: Не надо менять код с ошибкой на код из ответа. Так как в этом случае вопрос "как получить" не имеет смысла, потому что ты уже получаешь

Comment: ну ты подскажешь твой вариант ? да шас уберу

Answer (score 2):

В коде

```
arr.reduce((obj, total) => Object.values(obj) + total, 0)
```

самая первая ошибка, [перепутаны местами аргументы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

- obj - в этом аргументе храниться значение с предыдущей итерации
- total - в этом аргументе хранится объект.

Таким образом для правильного подсчета их надо поменять местами

```
arr.reduce((total, obj) => Object.values(obj) + total, 0)
```

Теперь происходит попытка сложить массив с числом. Вместо этого нужно складывать числа.

Решение зависит от того, какие объекты могут быть в массиве `arr`.

Если в объектах гарантированно только одно поле, достаточно просто привести полученный массив в число используя [оператор Унарный плюс](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus), либо функцию [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

```js
const arr = [{
  a: 1
}, {
  b: 2
}, {
  c: 3
}]
const totalValue = 6 // ?

console.log(arr.reduce((total, obj) => +Object.values(obj) + total, 0), totalValue);
console.log(arr.reduce((total, obj) => Number(Object.values(obj)) + total, 0), totalValue);
```

Если же полей в объекте может быть несколько, необходимо правильно по которым их нужно выбирать, какое-то конкретное, либо значения всех полей

Если нужна сумма всех полей, достаточно использовать еще один `.reduce`

```js
const arr = [{
  a: 1, a1: 4
}, {
  b: 2, b1: 5
}, {
  c: 3
}]
const totalValue = 15 // ?

console.log(arr.reduce((total, obj) => Object.values(obj).reduce((a,b)=>a+b,total), 0), totalValue);
```